# Is it ever acceptable to use "but" after a period/full stop

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

View the following text as a generic example, disregarding issues of context, etc.

> Stir constantly as the mixture begins to boil, watching the temperature regularly as the contents begins to settle within the pan. But be warned, <<[etc, etc]>>

I vaguely remember that "but" should never follow directly after a full stop, yet 'but' often falls directly after a pause in spoken conversation. Are there conditions that 'but' can be used after a full stop/period while writing? If not, what is the best way to make a notable pause before a 'but' in such a case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vaguely remembered "rule" may well have been issued by a harried English teacher in fourth grade who was trying to stop her students starting every sentence with "*But then ..*" or "*And then ..* ".

But starting a sentence with a coordinating conjunction is often exactly the right choice.

There is a discussion of this and other "*zombie rules*" on [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1185). Here is what linguist Mark Liberman has to say:

> There is nothing in the grammar of the English language to support a
>   prescription against starting a sentence with *and* or *but* --- nothing
>   in the norms of speaking and nothing in the usage of the best writers
>   over the entire history of the literary language. Like all languages,
>   English is full of mechanisms to promote coherence by linking a
>   sentence with its discourse context, and on any sensible evaluation,
>   this is a Good Thing. Whoever invented the rule against
>   sentence-intitial *and* and *but*, with its preposterous justification
>   in terms of an alleged defect in sentential "completeness", must have
>   had a tin ear and a dull mind. Nevertheless, this stupid made-up rule
>   has infected the culture so thoroughly that 60% of the American Heritage Dictionary's (sensible
>   and well-educated) usage panel accepts it to some degree.

Comment: +1. Of course, if you do this all the time it would make your writing sound choppy and unsophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into a novel you will find hundreds of "but" after a full stop.